# assignment with for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

I have 4 items.  Each item has a random number of locations with data at each location.  The code I have now loops through the locations and creates a data frame of location data.  I then want to take that location data, place it into a data frame for the corresponding item, and then move to the next location of that item, which will get added to the item data frame and so on until all of the locations for that item have been added to the item data frame.  I want it to then move to the next item and repeat the process for a separately named data frame.  For example, the data frame for item 1 should be named item1, the data frame for item 2 should be named item2 etc. I tried using the assign and paste0 functions to accomplish this, but paste0 creates a string and the assign function does not recognize that I want to assign the data to the data frame, rather than the string.  Sample code is posted below and any assistance that can be provided is much appreciated!

```
  for (p in 1:4) # 1-4 because there are 4 items
  {
    #Initialize the item data frame
    assign(paste0("item",p),data.frame(item_no=character(), x=integer(), y=integer(), data_val=integer()))

      #Loop through all locations for this item ID
      num_locations = sample(1:9,1) #Number of locations
      for (i in 1:(num_locations)){ #Loop through each location

        #Access data for current location (pulls from a database in actual code)

        ##################################################
        item_no <- p
        x <- sample(-3:3,1)
        y <- sample(-3:3,1)
        data_val <- sample(0:100,1)
        ##################################################

        #################DATA FRAME######################
        assign(paste0("location_data",i),data.frame(item_no, x, y, data_val))
        assign(paste0("item",p), data.frame(rbind(paste0("item", p), paste0("location_data", p))))


        #paste0 creates a string and therefore is not recognized that I want to call the data within itemp or location_datap
        #rbind needed because the loop through impact locations for a single item requries initialization of an empty data frame
        #for the first time through the location loop, the empty itemp data frame is overwritten by the location_datap data frame and supplemented each location thereafter


        ################################################
      }

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear and there are easier ways to solve your problem.  Using the assign statement is not generally recommended.  I would suggest a list of dataframes (see answer below) or one large dataframe with an extra column for your item number.  It all depends on your future analysis requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good idea to use lists instead of `assign` function. For example:

```
items <- list()
for (p in 1:4) {
    items[[p]] <- data.frame(...)
    ...
    items[[p]] <- rbind(items[[p]], ...)
}
```

Also this tip can be used for second loop.